# How can i will create local database witout using local host and firebase

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a registration and login app and whenever i want to fill registration form then all information should goes in local database and will able to login with these credentials. Please help me how can i will create this. I am stuck in this from last 10 days. My main focus local database and this database access in mobile without using internet or firebase.

Comment: You can use [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQLite` if you use `Expo` you can use [Expo SQLite](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite) and this [sample](https://github.com/expo/sqlite-example) may help you. also if you don't use expo you can use some sqlite wrapper like [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage)
another option that comes with React Native is [Async Storage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage)

Comment: can you send me proper example for that

Comment: @NehaSharma Of what ? async , expo sqlite ? which of them.